Is there a way to redirect to different links depending on the user's status?
import React from "react";
import {
 Card,
 CardContent,
 CardDescription,
 CardHeader,
 CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card";
import Link from "next/link";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { FaCircleCheck } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import ProButton from "@/components/elements/ProButton/pro-button";
type Props = {};

export const Pricing = async (props: Props) => {
 const user = await currentUser();

 return (
 <div>
   <div className="flex flex-col space-y-6 items-center md:space-y-12">
     <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 justify-center gap-8 items-center 
       max-w-[50rem] mx-auto">
       <Card
         className={cn(
           "h-[32.5rem] md:h-[37.5rem] flex flex-col relative overflow-hidden pt-4 
        items-start space-y-0 rounded-2xl"
         )}
        >
         <CardHeader>
           <CardTitle className="text-foreground/80 mb-3 md:mb-6 capitalize text-sm 
         md:text-base">
             Starter
           </CardTitle>
           <h2 className="text-4xl md:text-5xl font-semibold pb-4">
             Free
             <span className="text-sm md:text-base lg:text-xl font-medium">
               /month
             </span>
            </h2>
           <div className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
             <CardDescription className="text-black dark:text-white text-sm md:text- 
         base"> 
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
               Doloribus, delectus excepturi! Dolorem, omnis dolor blanditiis
               velit ipsum nam dolore? Unde.
             </CardDescription>
             <Link href="">
               <ProButton />
             </Link>
            </div>
          </CardHeader>
         <CardContent>
           <ul className="flex flex-col gap-2">
             <li className="flex items-center capitalize text-sm md:text-base">
               <FaCircleCheck className="mr-4 w-4 h-4 shrink-0" />
               Lorem ipsum
             </li>
             <li className="flex items-center capitalize text-sm md:text-base">
               <FaCircleCheck className="mr-4 w-4 h-4 shrink-0" />
               Lorem ipsum
             </li>
             <li className="flex items-center capitalize text-sm md:text-base">
               <FaCircleCheck className="mr-4 w-4 h-4 shrink-0" />
               Lorem ipsum
             </li>
           </ul>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 };

//pro-button.tsx
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useProModal } from "@/hooks/use-pro-modal";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import React, { useState } from "react";

type Props = {};

const ProButton = (props: Props) => {
const [recommended, setRecommended] = useState(false);
const proModal = useProModal();

return (
 <div>
   <Button
     variant={recommended ? "default": "outline"}
     className={cn(
       "w-full h-9",
       recommended === true
         ? ""
         : "border-2 border-black dark:border-white hover:border-muted 
            dark:hover:border-muted"
       )}
       onClick={proModal.onOpen}
     >
      Get started with Free
     </Button>
    </div>
  );
 };

 export default ProButton;

//pro-modal.tsx
"use client";
import {
 Dialog,
 DialogContent,
 DialogHeader,
 DialogTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { useProModal } from "@/hooks/use-pro-modal";

export const ProModal = () => {
 const proModal = useProModal();
 return (
 <Dialog open={proModal.isOpen} onOpenChange={proModal.onClose}>
   <DialogContent>
     <DialogHeader className="space-y-4">
       <DialogTitle className="text-center">Upgrade to Pro+</DialogTitle>
     </DialogHeader>
   </DialogContent>
 </Dialog>
 );
};

I am building a pricing page with nextJs and Clerk, and I was trying to redirect the user when they click on the "Get started with Free" button(if the user is authenticated, open the pro-modal, if not, send the user to the sign-in page), but I am struggling to make it work. I can redirect the user to 2 different pages based on the user state, but opening the modal on one hand, and sending the user to another page on the other hand seems quite tricky to me. The other problem is that I cannot keep the async-await with my client components in the same file, so that makes the problem even trickier to solve. Your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

You can pass the user as props to ProButton and change the onClick function on your button to do something like this conditionally:
const ProButton = (props: Props) => {
const [recommended, setRecommended] = useState(false);
const proModal = useProModal();

return (
 <div>
   <Button
     variant={recommended ? "default": "outline"}
     className={cn(
       "w-full h-9",
       recommended === true
         ? ""
         : "border-2 border-black dark:border-white hover:border-muted 
            dark:hover:border-muted"
       )}
       onClick={() => {
          // Check if there's a user and navigate or open modal
          !!props.user ? navigation.navigate("URI") : proModal.onOpen()
       }}
     >
      Get started with Free
     </Button>
    </div>
  );
 };

You have to add the useRouter from next to navigate, I just did an example but depending on what you're using to navigate it will do one thing or another
hope this helps!
